gitRootResult.stdout.toString().trim() - Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toString') - Dokcer
FYI: I am running npm install inside a docker image.
While doing npm install suddenly I am getting this error:
#22 140.3 npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated sinon@8.1.1: 16.1.1
#22 140.3 npm ERR! npm ERR! code 1
#22 140.3 npm ERR! npm ERR! path /root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-cloneFXk8EY/node_modules/npm-merge-driver-install
#22 140.3 npm ERR! npm ERR! command failed
#22 140.3 npm ERR! npm ERR! command sh -c node src/install.js
#22 140.3 npm ERR! npm ERR! /root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-cloneFXk8EY/node_modules/npm-merge-driver-install/src/get-root.js:8
#22 140.3 npm ERR! npm ERR!   const rootDir = gitRootResult.stdout.toString().trim();
#22 140.3 npm ERR! npm ERR!                                        ^
#22 140.3 npm ERR! npm ERR! 
#22 140.3 npm ERR! npm ERR! TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toString')
#22 140.3 npm ERR! npm ERR!     at getRoot (/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-cloneFXk8EY/node_modules/npm-merge-driver-install/src/get-root.js:8:40)
#22 140.3 npm ERR! npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-cloneFXk8EY/node_modules/npm-merge-driver-install/src/install.js:7:41)
#22 140.3 npm ERR! npm ERR!     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1198:14)
#22 140.3 npm ERR! npm ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1252:10)
#22 140.3 npm ERR! npm ERR!     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1076:32)
#22 140.3 npm ERR! npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:911:12)
#22 140.3 npm ERR! npm ERR!     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
#22 140.3 npm ERR! npm ERR!     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47
#22 140.3 npm ERR! 
#22 140.3 npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#22 140.3 npm ERR! npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2024-04-02T14_23_43_184Z-debug-0.log
#22 140.3 
#22 140.3 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#22 140.3 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2024-04-02T14_22_18_553Z-debug-0.log
#22 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c npm install --legacy-peer-deps" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

I've tried few things like:
npm install -g npm@latest

npm cache clean --force

rm -rf node_modules
npm install

npm update npm-merge-driver-install

Any info on this error will be highly apprecitated.

So git was not installed in the docker image.
Once I installed git this error went away.
